# I have a VBA code entered on Sheet 1. I want the code to work on Sheet 2. Do i just copy the code from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2?

Tags: excel, vba

I found this VBA code on here that works great. I want the code to work on the other worksheets in the workbook. The code works great in Sheet 1 but I would like the code to work on Sheet 2, Sheet 3, etc. as well. I tried copying the code from the Sheet 1 Module and pasted it into Sheet 2, Sheet 3, etc. to see if the code works. The code doesn't quite work as I anticipated it. I think I need to do something with the Standard Module code so that the code will work properly.

Sheet 1 Module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim rngToColor As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'get only used part of the sheet
    Set rng = Intersect(Me.UsedRange, Me.Range("A:Z"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitHere 

    For Each c In rng
        'check if previous value of this cell not equal to current value
        If cVals(c.Address) <> c.Text Then
            'if so (they're not equal), remember this cell
            c.ClearComments
            c.AddComment Text:="Changed value from '" & cVals(c.Address) & "' to '" & c.Text & "'" & " on " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & " by " & Environ("UserName")
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If

        'store current value of cell in dictionary (with key=cell address)
        cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
    Next c

ExitHere:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook Module

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Call populateDict
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Standard Module

```
Public cVals As New Dictionary

Sub populateDict()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:Z"))
        For Each c In rng
            cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
        Next c
        .Calculate
    End With

End Sub
```

Edit: I took the standard module and revised it to:

```
Sub populateDict()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:Z"))
        For Each c In rng
            cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
        Next c
        .Calculate
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:Z"))
        For Each c In rng
            cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
        Next c
        .Calculate
    End With

End Sub
```

this edit almost does the trick, but not sure why code isn't working correctly

Comment: Yeah, that would be one way to do it.  You may have to fix up all of the cell references.

Comment: The cell references are the same. I was thinking, can I just edit the code so that I only have to add the code to "thisworkbook" code instead of having to copy and paste the code for EACH worksheet?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is by placing the code in a separate module and then set your active sheet to a variable like this:

```
Sub myScript()
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    MsgBox (wks.Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

If you call this with Sheet1 active it will return the value from Sheet1.

---

[image]

---

Another method is by passing in the sheet as a variable to the sub.  Here is just one way to do this.  Add a button to each sheet that you want the macro to run from.  Double click each button in 'Design Mode' so that the VBA click event is opened in the editor.  Add a call to your sub like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call myScriptPass(ActiveSheet)

    'Or you can qualify it like this
    Call myScriptPass(Sheets(1))
End Sub
```

Now change your macro to this: (still located in a separate module)

```
Sub myScriptPass(wks As Worksheet)
    MsgBox (wks.Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**

Using the code you added to your post you can change it to the following:

```
Public cVals As New Dictionary

Sub record()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    With wks
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:Z"))
        For Each c In rng
            cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
        Next c
        .Calculate
    End With
End Sub
```

Now, it will run for which ever sheet is active.  So if you call the macro via button on Sheet1, then the code will run on Sheet1.

---

**Loop from main program**

```
Public cVals As New Dictionary

Sub myMainProgram()
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    'Loop thru each sheet in workbook example
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        Call record(wks)
    Next wks

    'Call subroutine for specific sheet example
    Call record(sheets("sheet1"))
End Sub

Sub record(wks As Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    With wks
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:Z"))
        For Each c In rng
            cVals(c.Address) = c.Text
        Next c
        .Calculate
    End With

    MsgBox ("Record macro was run on " & wks.Name & " worksheet.")
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a worksheet calculate event so the code will run once content in a cell has changed value. I included my code in the first post. Please see if you can tackle this.

Comment: Okay, see my edit.  BTW - how are you running the macro, is it a button on the sheet or from some other code?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. The macro is run from another code that I have. I'll try your revised code.

Comment: I've made another edit.  Now you have an example of calling the routine from another code block.  It shows how to loop through all your sheets and how to just send a specific sheet.

Comment: Your previous code raised my worksheet calculate event when I clicked on each sheet. i'll now try your enhanced code.

Comment: I think it'll be easier if I just include the codes that I have. These are codes that I found on here. Works great, but I want it to work on multiple worksheets in the same workbook. Please see my edit post.